# How to make a function to wait ajax data?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor4.x

I wrote a plugin for the CKEditor, which receives data from ajax and creates RichCombo.
Everything works fine, but when the editor has many instances on page - each plugin sends your ajax request, which creates an extra load.

I tried before sending a request to check whether the data is saved from the previous instance in a global variable, but ajax callback retains data after initialisation of all instances and variable is always empty.

I dont know how can send only one request and set data to all plugin instances.

Answer (score 0):

A plugin can init before you get Ajax response, therefore the global is empty.

You should have a array where you register all plugin instances.

On plugin init check if data is there if not register to wait for data.

A flag that will block all other request ( if ajax started ).

On Ajax callback for each plugin register do update.